# Why would Manage Display break when the content type machine name is a number?

Tags: entities, log-messages

Drupal 10.1.6
PHP 8.2.5

I am not sure how long ago it started, I just noticed it about a week ago. It only happens when the machine_name of the content type is numeric.

When I go to **/admin/structure/types/12345** I am able to edit, manage form display, manage fields, manage auto entity labels.. but when I try to Manage Display, the site breaks and I get the following error:

*TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, no array or string given in call_user_func_array() (line 72 of /app/docroot/core/modules/field_ui/src/Element/FieldUiTable.php)*

Recent log messages also show warnings below this error.

*Warning: Undefined array key "parent_wrapper" in Drupal\field_ui\Element\FieldUiTable::tablePreRender() (line 64 of /app/docroot/core/modules/field_ui/src/Element/FieldUiTable.php)*

*Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Drupal\field_ui\Element\FieldUiTable::tablePreRender() (line 64 of /app/docroot/core/modules/field_ui/src/Element/FieldUiTable.php)*

*Warning: Undefined array key "#region_callback" in Drupal\field_ui\Element\FieldUiTable::tablePreRender() (line 72 of /app/docroot/core/modules/field_ui/src/Element/FieldUiTable.php)*

Since it seemed to be coming from core, I set up a new D10.1.6 site and built a content type with a numeric machine name and it does not have an issue, works just fine. My current site has worked fine this way for years. This issue is very recent.

I am hoping someone might recognize this and answer What could be causing it?

Comment: The core error could be caused by any code, it's an incorrect `field_ui_table` render array. Do you use Field UI modules like Display Suite or Field Group?

Comment: Not really. 
The thing that gets me, though, is that it only happens when the machine_name in the url is numeric. None of the broken numeric machine named content types share fields or displays, but all of them are doing this. It's like something stopped converting the numeric value to a string or something.

Comment: I can't be sure but I feel like there was a bug report about this one in Drupal Core.